# Assembler: идеальный вывод содержимого регистров.

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Допустим, будем обсуждать вывод значения регистра AX в шестнадцатеричном беззнаковом формате (можно и в другом, просто в этом, как мне кажется, будет быстрее). Я представляю много способов написать такую процедуру, к примеру, для masm32:

```
ax_out proc uses dx cx
.code
push ax
mov ah,02h
mov cx,12d        //Счетчик на три цикла — каждый цикл будем отнимать от него 4
mainloop:
    pop dx
    push dx
    shr dx,cl     //Делаем сдвиг на 12/8/4, получая нужную нам цифру в 0-3 битах dl
    and dl,0Fh    //Очищаем биты 4-7 в dl
    cmp dl,10d    //Если это буква, то для получения кода прибавляем к ней 37
    jge add_37h
    add dl,30h    //Ну а если цифра, — то 30
    jmp print_4
    add_37h:
        add dl,37h
    print_4:
        int 21h
    sub cx,3
loop mainloop
pop dx            //А теперь поторяем это все для последней цифры.
push dx
and dl,0fh
cmp dl,10d
jge add_37h_last
add dl,30h
jmp print_last
add_37h_last:
    add dl,37h
print_last:
    int 21h
pop ax
ret
ax_out endp
```

Выглядит не лучшим образом. Поэтому я бы хотел увидеть код, которым бы вы (люди разбирающиеся в ассемблере лучше меня) стали выводить содержимое регистра AX.
Я понимаю, что можно написать программу либо с упором на место занимаемое ею в памяти, либо на ее скорость, но всё же, если бы у вас была задача написать универсальный вывода AX на экран — как бы это выглядело?

Comment: Что понимается под универсальностью? Вывод в разных форматах (signed/unsigned binary/hexademical/decimal/float)?

Comment: Я бы выдал для начала hex-значение. В зависимости от задачи, если это каждый из байтов значения представляет собой видимый символ (значение >= 32), можно вывести ещё и сам символ (в кавычках, чтобы было ясно). Как лучше сделать на ассемблере, не знаю т.к. не спец.

Comment: >>Что понимается под универсальностью? Вывод в разных форматах (signed/unsigned binary/hexademical/decimal/float)?

Достаточно одного формата, hex, подойдет лучше всего, я думаю. Без знаков, просто "как есть" в памяти, просто переведенным в hex ("0001", "FFFE").

Comment: Так в чем состоит требуемая универсальность?

Comment: >Я понимаю, что можно написать программу либо с упором на место занимаемое ею в памяти, либо на ее скорость

Это было написано в отношении этого предложения. Не надо писать две программы — "самую быструю" и "самую маленькую". Нужна просто программа, которую бы вы написали, не зная для какой конечной задачи она будет использоваться.

Comment: А почему masm32? 16-bit dos программа... Для 8086/8088... Палеонтология.

Comment: @Omenabaka тогда я возьму C/С++ и не буду заниматься фигней. Ассемблер в связке с ЯВУ используется исключительно для оптимизаций, писать на нем "универсальный код" - абсолютно глупо, если не сказать жестче.

Answer (score 4):

Когда-то давно решал такую задачу с условием минимального размера кода. Получилось два варианта. Знание того, как отражаются результаты операций на флагах, могут помочь избежать лишних сравнений. Хотя, конечно, страдает читаемость и понятность кода.

Первый вариант:

```
    .model tiny
    .code
    .386
    .startup
    mov     bx,es
cyc:
    shld    ax,bx,4
    and     al,0fh
    daa
    add     al,0f0h
    adc     al,40h
    int     29h
    shl     bx,4
    jnz     short cyc
    ret

    end
```

Второй вариант:

```
    .model tiny
    .code
    .startup
    .386

    mov     bx,es
cyc:
    shld    ax,bx,4
    aaa
    ja      short notbig
    add     al,11h
notbig: add     al,30h
    int     29h
    shl     bx,4
    jnz     short cyc

    ret

    end
```

Comment: Только вот для ТС не мешало бы **основательно** откомментировать.

Comment: @avp имхо, это довольно интересный код, разобравшись в котором можно узнать много нового. Оставим это для любопытных :)

Comment: А Вы, я смотрю, любитель *задавать* загадки.

Comment: +1, особенно за `aaa` :) хотя насчёт читаемости ассемблерного кода вы ведь пошутили, правда?

Comment: @VladD скорее я погорячился, употребив слово "читаемость" применительно к асму :)

Comment: @a_gura: кстати, а не скорее ли будет сделать lookup-таблицу? (из [этого](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Assembler/comp.lang.asm.x86/2005-01/0242.html) обсуждения)

Comment: @VladD Надо проверять. Может быть будет и быстрее.

Comment: Это сильно от процессора может зависеть. Для 8086 или i286 одно,  а для, скажем, i5 уже по другому (конвейер, несколько однотипных функциональных устройств, переупорядочивание команд и  т.п.).

Comment: инструкции AAA n DAA невалидны в х64

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант без условия. Когда-то делал такое. Линейный алгоритм

```
.486
mov eax,12345678h
bswap eax  ; делаем байты задом-наперёд
push eax     
aam 16 ; теперь ah - старшая цифра по основанию 16, al младшая
push ax ; сохранили младшую цифру
mov al,  ah ; сначало старшую
aam     ; разобрали по основанию 10
aad 17  ; собрали по основанию 17
add 30  ; добавили 0
mov ah,0eh
int 10h
pop ax; вернули "младшую цифру"    
aam 
aad 17
add 30
mov ah,0Eh     
int 10h ; 
pop eax ; вернули всё
mov al,ah ; "сдвиг" на 8 бит
; повтор
bswap eax
xchg al,ah ; "сдвиг" на 16 бит двумя командами
; повтор
mov al,ah ; "сдвиг" на 8 бит
; повтор
```

Если ваш ассемблер `aad 17` не понимает  - пишем `db 0D5h, 17;`
для `aam 16` код `db 0D4,16;`, для `bswap eax` код `db 0Fh, 0C8h;` на последнюю команду акцентирую внимание - она хорошо подходит если вы пишете видео-декодер, там часто такое надо [bswap](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/DataTypes/T77_0230_bswap.htm). "сдвиг" означает что вместо сдвига используются более легкие команды, из-за которых младшие 8 бит оказываются на нужном месте, а не настоящий сдвиг который больше ЦП ест. С порядком цифр мог напутать, значения цифр будут те что надо.

10-тое прерывание ф-ция 0Eh выводит одну цифру. Работает как из под DOS так и в случае если нету OS. Можно выводить значения регистров если пишите загрузчик или свою OS.